# What is difference between instantiating variable inside constructor and directly in class + Typescript / Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
export class ReactiveFormOne {
  studentA: Student = new Student();

  studentB: Student;

  constructor (){
    this.studentB = new Student();
  }
}
```

What is the fundamental difference between `studentA` and `studentB`?

Comment: Nothing, in such a trivial case. But what if you need to instantiate it with something that isn't available until the form itself is instantiated (e.g. an injected dependency)?

Comment: Did you mean `this.studentB = new Student();`?

Comment: You could check transpiled version and see that in your case both are equivalent `function ReactiveFormOne() {
            this.studentA = new Student();
            this.studentB = new Student();
        }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are effectively identical. A class property initializer is transpiled into an equivalent assignment following the first `super` call, or the first statement(s) of the constructor if there is no `super` call.

I would recommend putting order-dependent initializations in the constructor body since future maintainers will generally be less eager to re-order statements in blocks, but may e.g. re-order initialized properties declared in the class body to conform to style guides.

Comment: so Constructor is merely to pull providers / services i.e., to inject dependencies is it ? I come from Java background n with very little Angular 1 knowledge so bear with me.